# Do we always need to use 'self' before a variable?

Tags: python, class, maya, self

Do I **always** need to use 'self' when creating a variable? I'm finding that there are actually a lot of times when when I'm creating variables and would prefer to not use the `self` argument.

A super simple example of this is below. (Scripting in Autodesk Maya) I've created a method that creates a group, assigns the name of it to variable `groupName` (this is just because if two objects have the same name it automatically adds a number on the end) and then returns that variable.

```
def createGroup(self):
    cmds.group(name = "FBX_Export_Group", em = True)
    groupName = cmds.ls(sl = True)[0]

    return groupName
```

Then, back in the `__init__` method, I've got the following line,

```
self.exportGroup = self.createGroup()
```

which is both calling the method and assigning the returned variable to one that can be used class wide. This is just a simple example. One note that may be important is that currently there is only one instance of this class being created each time the script runs.

I really like this way of working because I find it easier to keep track of all my variables this way, as well as identifying which variables are being used only in one method and which ones are being used throughout the script. It also means less typing overall.

At the moment, the code works exactly the same as if I was working with `self.groupName` (or any variable).  What I'm wondering is, is there any specific reason why I should **always** use the `self` argument? Will not using `self` before a variable cause problems when I start using more than one instance of the class? Is it just good practice? All the tutorials I've seen so far seem to do it that way but I don't get why it **needs** to be done that way.

Comment: No, you only need to use `self` if you want to modify a property of the current object. There are a ton of other things you can do in Python besides modifying object properties... so again: no.

Comment: You stroke a `self.cat` and this particular cat purrs. You stroke a `cat` and all cats of the world purr.

Comment: @Alex Or perhaps just your local cat, depends...

Comment: Think of `self` as what `this` is to C++/Java. A variable defined within the constructor or a method without `self` will have local scope, with `self` it becomes a member of the class. If this make no sense then probably you need to refresh the fundamentals of object oriented programming.

Comment: @Alex.S It can either be all cats of the world purr as you point out or just your local temporary imaginary cat as @deceze points out, depending on where `cat` is defined.